# How to get rid of jaggies in math symbols in concrete and ccfonts?

Tags: fonts

`concrete` and `ccfonts` packages render math symbols not in vector form but as bitmapped. How can I get rid of this?

I added an example snapshot from [free latex math fonts,Fig.4](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) which seems to have same behavior . You can see the difference in math and text characters. I have no problem with Euler version of math symbols

[image]

Comment: Only by changing fonts. These as you say  are bitmapped fonts and this is one of their many limitations.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: You could try [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) for `concrete` if you use LuaTex or XeTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Only by changing fonts. These as you say are bitmapped fonts and this is one of their many limitations.

Comment: i guessed that i should find type-1 versions of these fonts, searching type1 concrete math fonts yields only commercial Micropress fonts. I couldn't find a free substitute font.

Comment: @HakanTiftikci: you can use `mftrace` to create autotraced type1 version of the fonts, the result will not be "professional" quality but it can be better than bitmap fonts.